# Area between curves with respect to $x$ or $y$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Sketch the region enclosed by the curves given below. Decide whether to integrate with respect to $x$ or $y$. Then find the area of the region.  $y=3\cos(x)$ , $y=3−\frac{6x}{\pi}$

Need help with solving this question. I did $\int_0^{\pi/2} [3\cos(x)- (3−\frac{6x}{\pi})]dx$ and got the answer $0.6438$ but it says the answer is wrong. Calculated in radians

Any tips on where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing other bounded area from $x=\pi/2$ to $x=\pi$

Notice, the line $y=3-\frac{6x}{\pi}$ intersects the $y=3\cos x$ at three distinct points $x=0,\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi$. Therefore you can split bounded area into two parts & integrating with proper limits as follows
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}(3\cos x-3+\frac{6x}{\pi})\ dx+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}(3-\frac{6x}{\pi}-3\cos x)\ dx$$
$$=3-\frac{3\pi}{4}+3-\frac{3\pi}{4}=6-\frac{3\pi}{2}\approx 1.28761102$$

Comment: ohh alright thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have the right integral but the wrong limits:

[image]

Comment: ohh thanks makes sense